# How does MSLinqToSqlGenerator determine the return type of a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

### I have a stored procudre (SP) as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UDSPSelectMissing]
    -- paramters omitted
AS
BEGIN 
    -- Code Omitted
    SELECT 
        c.MemberID,
        c.FirstName,
        c.MiddleName,
        c.LastName,
        c.Suffix,
        c.PhoneHome,
        c.PhoneCell,
        c.Email
        FROM [dbo].[Members] c
        WHERE c.MemberID IN (SELECT MemberID FROM #PeopleCameMissing)
        ORDER BY c.LastName,c.FirstName
END
```

When I added the SP to the SP pane of "dbml" designer, I was expecting MSLinqToSqlGenerator to create "ISingleResult" as return value type.  To my surprise, the return value type is "int".  Clearly, the generator is using certain criteria to determine the return value type.  I have other similar SPs that returns "ISingleResult" type.

**Does anybody know what would cause the generator to behave this way?**

By the way, somebody on this site suggested recreating the SP, removing the reference from "dbml", restarting Visual Studio (VS) and adding to it to "dbml" again.  I went through all that to no avail.

My suspicion lies with the temporary table "#PeopleCameMissing".

Any comments or suggestions are most welcome!

Thanks,

Cullen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I mentioned in my original post that I suspected the temp table.  The temp table was created by "SELECT INTO #PeopleCameMissing" command therefore its definition is dynamic so when the stored procedure is added to "dbml" designer, the generator has no clue about the table's definition.  What if I let the table definition known to the generator, maybe I'd be able to get the desired return type.  Based on this conjecture, I ran a test.  I declared a table as follows:

```
    DECLARE @PeopleCameMissing TABLE(
        MemberID int,
        FirstName nchar(20),
        MiddleName nchar(20),
        LastName nchar(20),
        Suffix nchar(10),
        PhoneHome nchar(20),
        PhoneCell nchar(20),
        Email  nchar(80)
    );
```

---

And changed the original statement as follows:

```
    INSERT INTO @PeopleCameMissing (
        MemberID,
        FirstName,
        MiddleName,
        LastName,
        Suffix,
        PhoneHome,
        PhoneCell,
        Email)
    SELECT 
        c.MemberID,
        c.FirstName,
        c.MiddleName,
        c.LastName,
        c.Suffix,
        c.PhoneHome,
        c.PhoneCell,
        c.Email
        FROM [dbo].[Members] c
        WHERE c.MemberID IN (SELECT a.MemberID FROM #PeopleCameMissing a)
        ORDER BY c.LastName,c.FirstName;

    DROP TABLE #PeopleCameMissing;

    SELECT * 
        FROM @PeopleCameMissing 
        ORDER BY LastName,FirstName;
```

---

And then I added the stored procedure to "dbml" designer again.  This time the generator created the desired return type: "ISingleResult".  It seems to prove my conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple (under special conditions).

SQL allows you to interrogate the resultset schema without calling a procedure.

Under the not so special conditions*, SQL will give you alternate answers on every invocation.

`*` Those with IF statements. This may be intentional. I dont know SQL well enough to answer that.